# getting response from web service using mule CE

Tags: mule, esb

You can see below my project. I send data to a web service and when i'm testing with postman, i get the response of the web service, which is in json format: {"success":0,"failed":1}.
Now i want to get this reponse in my mule because i need to complete a test with the result. Thank you in advance.
[image]
Test with postman:

[image]
Now i will add "Choice component" if success = 1 and failed =
0 then "logger with a message it's ok" if not i will do another thing.

Comment: Please add the HTTP request you create with Postman (including headers, params, etc) since that is what you want to do with mule now.

Comment: Thank you @afelisatti for your reply. you can see now my updated question.

Comment: if you are already getting the response from this web service, you can set payload after the http outbound with #[message.payload] MEL expression wrapped with http response builder .. that will work

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary this is the first time I work with these components so if you can tell me where to add what is missing or give me an example, I would be grateful.

Comment: i tried this: http://pastebin.com/qkX9pkEc . but it didn't work, any answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After http outbound endpoint put  `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>`

and then in **choice component** the that expression `#[message.payload.success]` is 1 and `#[message.payload.failed]` is 0 then log **ok** or else do other thing

**UPDATE**
After you get the response as `{"success":0,"failed":1}` put  `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>`
and extract the values in following expression MEL :-

```
#[message.payload.success]  and #[message.payload.failed]
```

and then in **choice component** the that expression `#[message.payload.success]` is 1 and `#[message.payload.failed]` is 0 then log **ok** or else do other thing

Comment: Put a logger after http outbound with #[message.payload] and tell me what you get

Comment: I get this message: org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream@182e429

Comment: Could you pls put an object to String tranformer or http response to string transformer before logger and tell me what you get

Comment: with #[message.payload] it's working and gives the result but when i try #[message.payload.success] it gives null ans this is normal because we have string now. So i tried object to json but it gives error.

Comment: wait wait .. I will give you solution .. just confirm me that you are getting the json respone in message.payload

Comment: Yes when i added the transformer and logger i get message payload in string format.

Comment: are you getting {"success":0,"failed":1} in log in #[message.payload] ?

Comment: yes and with #[message.payload.success] i  get null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74719/discussion-between-anirban-sen-chowdhary-and-rajeun).